# Flash 8 FileReference and file integrity check

Tags: flash, actionscript, filereference

Flash 8 FileReference API gives you the possibility to check periodically for the number of bytes being transmitted:

```
listener.onProgress = function(file:FileReference, bytesLoaded:Number, bytesTotal:Number):Void {
    trace("onProgress with bytesLoaded: " + bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal: " + bytesTotal);
}
```

(more infos [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002204.html) and [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002204.html))

In case of upload, **would you suggest to use this method to check for the integrity of the uploaded file**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just listen to the onComplete event to check whenever the file is properly uploaded.
If no error events have been thrown so far the file *should* be on the server.

If you don't want to trust FlashPlayer regarding the *integrety* of the posted file (e.g. your server failed moving it from the /tmp folder, etc. ), something likely would be necessary to make sure the procedure was finished properly :

- Check the file size (best would be checksum, don't think you can get that though) client side.
- Post this information within the file upload request.
- Once the post data received, gather the same information (size, checksum) server-side from the received file and compare it with the information generated client-side.
- Send back status (fail/success)

... Unless your application is very sensible I would skip this though, just for the simple reason that it might generate more problems than if you hadn't got any integrity-check at all : )

Better: depending on the file you send you may be able to find out a server script to check if the file looks fine and just send back a status depending on that.